# Retrofit mapping from Json Expect Array and get Object

Tags: android, json, retrofit

I have Json:

```
 {
       "data":[
            "name": "name1",
            "surname": "surname1",
            "id": "22",
            "motivations": []
        },
        "1:"{
            "name": "name2",
            "surname": "surname2",
            "id": "23",
            "motivations": []
        },
        {
            "name": "name3",
            "surname": "surname3",
            "id": "24",
            "motivations": []
        }],
        "sign": "9e46b7d6b140b",
        "last_call": 1446
    }
```

Model class:

```
class Person{
        @DatabaseField
        String name;
        @DatabaseField
        String surname;
        @DatabaseField(id = true)
        int id;
        @DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.SERIALIZABLE)
        List<Motivation> motivations
    }

public interface ApiService {
   public static final String TEST_SIGN = "test_KP1FE3R1";
  @GET("api/person/{id}")
    Call<JsonObject>getPerson(@Path("id") String id, @QueryMap Map<String, String> options);

}
```

API Client

```
public static Retrofit getClient() {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
                .setLenient() .create();
        if (retrofit==null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
```

Helper class

```
public static void getPerson(Callback<List<Person>> callback, Context context, Map<String,String> params){
        mContext=context;
        ApiService apiService = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiService.class);
        Map<String,String> queryMap = getQueryMap(LAST_MUSEUM_EVENT_CALL_TIMESTAMP,params);
        Call<List<Person>> call= apiService.getPerson(queryMap);
        call.enqueue(callback);

    }
```

And my main ActivityPart when I make a response:

```
ApiHelper.getPerson(new Callback<List<Person>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<List<Person>> call, Response<List<Person>> response) {



                      List<Person> mlist = response.body();


                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<List<Person>> call, Throwable t) {
                        Log.i(TAG,"ERROR"+ t.getMessage());
                    }
                },MainActivity.this,options);
```

The url of my request is correct but Ive got error like this:

> Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $

Comment: your person details are under jsonarray data not jsonobject

Comment: yes and I want to map it to the list of persons

Comment: you can have arraylist of person data. i suggest use a json to pojo generator online. Also you can get rid of unwanted json wrapper with a custom converter. check this https://github.com/nickbutcher/plaid/commit/4e338a5

Comment: Your json response is wrong, make it proper

Comment: @Bhavnik edited in my problem the json is just like updated.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON response it's malformed.

```
{
   "data":[
        "name": "name1",
        "surname": "surname1",
        "id": "22",
        "motivations": []
    },
    "1:"{
        "name": "name2",
        "surname": "surname2",
        "id": "23",
        "motivations": []
    },
    {
        "name": "name3",
        "surname": "surname3",
        "id": "24",
        "motivations": []
    }],
    "sign": "9e46b7d6b140b",
    "last_call": 1446
}
```

After "data" you have an opening bracket that marks the start of an array. But before the array ends, yo have a closing curly bracket that's ending the object. There's something wrong there.